# iText 7 .Net referencing

Tags: c#, itext

I have used iText in the past...so I'm not completely green. However after installing the NuGet iText 7 dot net package, I can't seem to figure out the references to iText7. 
Is it not just : 
using iText.text.pdf.parser;
using iText.text.pdf;

And so on?

Comment: iText 7 has been rewritten from scratch and is not backwards compatible. So none of your old code will work without some changes. Take a look at the Jumpstart Tutorial: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm looking to extract data from a pdf, would you be familiar with how to do that in the newer version? Also would it be wiser to just use itextsharp maybe? Thanks all.

Comment: IText 7 is the product that is going to be further improved.  In iText(Sharp) 5 only major bugs might be fixed. Thus,  if you are interested in new features and improvements (like explicit support for PDF 2.0), port to iText 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text extraction API is pretty much the same in iText 7 as in iText 5, only in iText 7 there are a number of bugs that have been fixed over the last year, and work is underway to improve the tooling. The namespace of the text extraction API in iText 7 is `iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser`.

There isn't a direct mapping for most classes and use cases, because most functionality has simply been reimplemented with a different way of working. Rather than doing old things with new tools, we prefer that users understand the new tooling and start doing new things with it. In the core functionality, only the text extraction and digital signatures APIs are very similar to iText 5, and for all the rest we recommend looking at the tutorials, most prominently the Building Blocks and the Jump-Start tutorial.

For the record: I am an iText Software employee.

Comment: Is there a namespace documentation, list or something? Where I can see a mapping of the old ones to the new ones? Thanks again for the help guys.

Comment: I'll add my comment to the answer

Comment: excellent thank you. Can you point me to a similar tutorial for text extract?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in my .NET Framework 4.7.2 project.

Be completely sure you're using the right version. As a first (not the most clever) solution you can try installing from your Nuget Package the different version until you get the right one (I mean, until the red squiggling line under your using is gone, see the next screenshot).

[image]

For some reason, VS does not seem to detect automatically the right version your project may need.

A quicker way of finding the right version is going back to a machine where iText is working for that specific project, and accessing the "View in Object Browser" window. There you can read the correct version of iText you are looking for. In your project go to `Project` → `References` → Right click on the iText reference → `View in object browser` And here you should be able to see the dll version of the package, something like: `C:\Users\<userName>\Repos\<theSolution>\packages\itext7.7.1.16\lib\net45\itext.forms.dll`

I followed this steps and the namespaces I was missing were all found.